# Not working any more

Tags: python, error

I use Windows 10

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 75)
Build: 2019-07-29 09:41 AM Windows 
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --python-expr
argv[3] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
read file 
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 48000hz, got 44100hz instead
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x5801B2C4
Module  : C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atioglxx.dll
```

Comment: That looks like an issue with your graphics driver. Try to update it to the most recent version and check if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Should be posted to [SU], this deals with system issues (e.g graphics drivers)